# How to get default calendar type in Java

Tags: java, calendar, locale, globalization

Is there any way to get information about default calendar type used in specified location? (Gregorian, Chinese...)

I can get `Calendar` object with:

```
DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, new Locale("en","us"));
Calendar c = formatter.getCalendar();
```

However I do not see any information about calendar type.

I managed to do it in .NET so maybe there is something similar in JAVA.

Thanks

Comment: Also take a look at [`Locale.getDefault()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

Should be for **default**:

```
Calendar.getInstance();
```

And for **locale**:

```
Calendar.getInstance(locale); //e.g. locale= new Locale("de", "ch");
```

Comment: Thanks but How do I know if it is for example Gregorian Calendar or if it is Islamic calendar?

Comment: Calendar is calendar. The locale is dependant of the system. You get it by Locale.getDefault(). From there you can check, for example .getCountry()